# Ubuntu 22.04 hangs on reboot

Tags: 22.04, reboot

Tried everything and can't find the answer anywhere. I installed Ubuntu 22.04 as single OS on a new HP15-dy2. Boots fine and everything works. Only problem is that Ubuntu does not reboot, not from the menu and not from the terminal. Cold boot works OK, no problem there and no error-messages (after getting rid of secure boot and other BIOS security-features). Once cold-booted everything works fine.

Hardware is HP15-dy2, with 8G memory, an intel i5 processor, Realtek sound and iris-xe integrated graphics. Ubuntu-version 22.04 with the 6.2 kernel (upgraded from 5.19, but the upgrade did not solve the problem).

Sometimes when it hangs on reboot I get a message telling me the journal needed of needs to be cleaned or something like that.

It's not a very big problem, since shutting down and booting cold is no problem at all, but it is annoying.

Any suggestions or help is much appreciated!

Update:
Tried to wait for a while for the reboot to complete, but eventually I just got a black screen, with the computer still 'on'. The journalctl commands showed only some comments about gtk not being initialized, but that's 'problem' is solved. Somehow, during either the shutting-down part or the restart-part of the reboot, the journal is not completed, but I don't know if that's the real problem and I don't know what is the real problem. Upgraded to kernel 6.2.5. All older kernels are uninstalled, but the kernel doesn't seem to be part of the solution.

Comment: Perhaps it takes longer than you waited. Try waiting longer, reboot, and `sudo journalctl  -b  -1 -e` to see the end of the previous  boot's log.  Read `man journalctl`, and use the "`-b #`" option to access earlier reboot. Use `sudo journalctl  --list-boots`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried leaving it after reboot for a while, but eventually I get a black screen, although the computer is still 'on'. This is what I get when I do the journal comments:

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried leaving it after reboot for a while, but eventually I get a black screen, although the computer is still 'on'. This is what I get when I do the journal comments:
Mar 11 10:07:34 arjan-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx snapd-desktop-i[2141]: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Mar 11 10:07:34 arjan-HP-Laptop-15-dy2xxx snapd-desktop-integration.snapd-desktop-integration[2141]: Failed to do gtk init

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers (who have better answers). Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our way to help you improve your question. All facts about your system and problem should go in the Question with [edit].  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Help us help you.